# Orientation error:'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to force orientation on a view using this code.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

What happens is the view loads in the simulator in landscape and when I turn it to portrait the app crashes and I get this error `'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'`. What I would like to happen is that when you turn it into portrait it remains in landscape and doesn't crash.
[image: The supported orientations are in the info.plist]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you try to return NO in shouldAutorotate?

Comment: - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
Description: 
"This method is only called if the view controller’s shouldAutorotate method returns YES."

Comment: @Nico please look at Morkrom comments, why do you return NO ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: sorry, I missunderstood the question